# Constructibility of LCTs of graded sequence of ideals from symbolic powers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective variety of dimension $n\geq4$ and $Y\subset X$ an irreducible subvariety of codimension $c$. Let $\frak{a}_{\bullet}=\{\frak{a}_\it m\}$ be the graded sequence of ideals on $X$ given by $\frak{a}_\it m:=\mathcal{I}_Y^{<cm>}$, where $\mathcal{I}_Y^{<p>}$ is the $p$-th symbolic power of $\mathcal{I}_Y$. How to show that the log canonical threshold $\text{LCT}(\frak{a}_{\bullet};\it x)$ is a constructible function on $X$?